# Перевод статьи из справки «What are declined flags, and what should I do about them?»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, тревоги

Появилась новая страница справки, требующая перевода: [What are declined flags, and what should I do about them?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags).

Comment: Accepted?   (◕‿◕)♡

Comment: @Suvitruf я уже и забыл, что это мой вопрос :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Что такое отклонённые тревоги и что с ними делать?

#### Что означает «тревога отклонена»?

Модератор (или другой проверенный участник сообщества) может отклонить [тревогу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), которую вы оставили, чтобы сообщить о найденной проблеме.

#### Почему моя тревога могла быть отклонена?

Существует множество причин, из-за которых тревогу могли отклонить:

- Другие участники могли не согласиться с тем, что выявленная вами проблема существует (например, вы предлагали закрыть вопрос как «не по теме», но вопрос соответствует [тематике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) сайта).
- Проблема могла относиться к числу тех, с которыми вы могли бы справиться самостоятельно (например, вы отметили неправильный ответ тревогой, против которого моли бы проголосовать или улучшить его правкой).
- Проблема могла быть уже исправлена ​​к моменту проверки тревоги (например, автор вопроса отредактировал его после того, как вы оставили тревогу).
- Проблема могла остаться незамеченной (например, вы отметили комментарий как оскорбительный за [пранк](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ), но модератор, обрабатывающий тревогу, не перешел по ссылке).

Обычно модераторы указывают конкретную причину отклонения тревоги. Вы можете просмотреть их, посетив страницу [истории тревог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current).

#### Что делать, если мою тревогу отклонили?

Делать что–то особенное *не* нужно, но если проблема всё еще существует и вы хотите исправить ситуацию:

- Попробуйте выяснить, почему тревога была отклонена (см. выше). Возможно, коллеги, обрабатывающие тревогу, что-то упустили... Возможно, не учли что–то вы. И это прекрасная возможность разобраться в системе глубже.
- Затем, перейдите к сообщению, которое вы отметили тревогой. Посмотрите, осталась ли проблема. Возможно, проблемы уже нет или она более не кажется вам важной.

Если проблема всё ещё существует, пожалуйста, подумайте, как вы можете решить её самостоятельно:

- Достаточно ли будет [проголосовать против](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) сообщения, чтобы его посетило меньше участников?
- Можете ли вы улучшить сообщение [правкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing), учитывая при этом намерения автора?

Если вы можете решить проблему самостоятельно, нет необходимости оставлять тревогу - просто исправьте проблему!

Если вы не можете исправить проблему самостоятельно или вы считаете, что произошло недоразумение при рассмотрении, воспользуйтесь тревогой «требуется вмешательство модератора». В комментарии к тревоге укажите все необходимые детали, которые, возможно, были упущены при первой обработке тревоги.

В случаях, когда тревога откланяется из-за недопонимания между вами и проверяющим участником, вы можете задать вопрос на Мете. Вопрос на Мете — прекрасный способ обсудить конкретный случай со всем сообществом и, возможно, убедить проверяющих пересмотреть подход к проверке тревог. Пожалуйста, уделите вопросу время: детально опишите ситуацию, обязательно поясните, как предлагаемые изменения, улучшат сайт для всего сообщества, предоставьте примеры.

#### Что произойдет, если много моих тревог будут отклонены?

После того, как некоторое количество ваших тревог будут отклонены, вы увидите предупреждение, предлагающее посетить страницу истории ваших тревог. Если четверть и более оставленных вами тревог за последние 7 дней будут отклонены, вы временно не сможете использовать тревоги. Ограничение может длиться до семи дней, после чего возможность оставлять сигналы тревоги появится у вас снова. Мы надеемся, что за это время вы сможете просмотреть оставленные вами тревоги, учтёте советы из этой статьи, и вернетесь к модерированию более информированным.

Пожалуйста, помните, сайт продолжает работать исключительно благодаря таким участникам как вы. Чем эффективней мы разрешаем возникающие проблемы вместе, тем лучше становится $SiteName для всех!

Смотрите также:

- [Привилегия «отмечать тревогой»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391/260198).
- [How do I properly use the “Not an Answer” flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/260198).
- [Allow recovery from flag hellban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/).

Comment: Что такое отклоненный флаг? -- забыли ё; по которым флаг -- из-за которых, думаю, будет лучше; подняли флаг -- оставили тревогу; (вообще все флаги  ̶(̶в̶ ̶г̶о̶с̶т̶и̶ ̶б̶у̶д̶у̶т̶ ̶к̶ ̶н̶а̶м̶)̶ надо заменить на тревоги); который вы пометили -- о котором вы сообщили, а то всяких животных представляешь... _пометили_ везде -- _отметили_ в таком случае; но если проблема всё ещё... -- но, если...; Так что, имя это ввиду... -- стоит убрать вообще. Я посмотрел часть текста (на остальное потом, мб, взгляну); жаль, нет прав править посты у вас на Мете. А так -- хороший перевод!

Comment: @Aer спасибо. Подключайтесь к программированию и отвечайте у нас, тогда сможете :D

Comment: Внес небольшую правку и добавил перевод в справку. Пожалуйста, дайте знать, если у вас есть какие–либо замечания.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky небольшая правка после большой правки :-D

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky спасибо. Только **учтете** -> **учтёте**. Не любите вы Ё =/